# CMake unexpectedly prepending last filename to executable in foreach

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm attempting to create a CMakeLists.txt for a library project I'm working on. It's a fairly simple structure, and I've been able to recreate a simple example of the issue I'm running into with the following setup:

```
project
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   ├── doctest.hpp
│   └── foo.hpp
└── src
    ├── foo.cpp
    ├── bar.cpp
    └── test-main.cpp
```

with the example code available in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/RPiAwesomeness/2c84a53da0cdb67c724d2b1973de434e) (`_` substituted for `/` for gists). The C++ sources and headers don't actually affect the problem, so I'm not including their contents, but my CMakeLists.txt is effectively this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(foo VERSION 0.0.1)

set(source_files
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo.cpp
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/bar.cpp
)

set(header_files
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/foo.hpp
)

set(DOCTEST_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
add_library(Doctest IMPORTED INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(Doctest INTERFACE ${DOCTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(test-main OBJECT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/test-main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test-main Doctest)

foreach(src ${source_files})
        # Strip off leading path and extension, leaving only filename without extension to be ${testName}
        string(REGEX MATCH "^.*/src/(.*)\\.[^.]*$" "" ${src})
        set(testName ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
        message(STATUS ${testName})

        add_executable("${testName}" "${src}" $<TARGET_OBJECTS:test-main>)
        target_include_directories(${testName} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
        add_test(NAME ${testName} COMMAND ${testName})
endforeach()
```

The issue is that although `cmake .` runs fine, as does `make`, instead of the output executable being `src/[filenameWithoutExtensionHere]` as I would expect it to be (from [line 24 in CMakeLists](https://gist.github.com/RPiAwesomeness/2c84a53da0cdb67c724d2b1973de434e#file-cmakelists-txt-L24)) it ends up as
`src/bar.cppfoo` and `src/bar.cppbar`, apparently prepending the final filename in the sources list to the executable.

Is this caused by something I'm not aware of in my usage of `foreach` or in my calling of `add_executable`? The `message(STATUS ${testName})` call prints what I would expect, just the filename without path or extension. I've also tried various combinations of quoting/not quoting `${testName}` in the `add_executable` as well as removing `NAME` and `COMMAND` from `add_test` but I don't think that is a part of this. This is my first project using CMake and I'm kinda lost as to why this is happening.

What is causing the prepending of the final source filename and how can I avoid it?

Comment: @Thomas I made the change you suggested and I'm still getting the issue. Could it be a change in CMake? I'm currently on version 3.13.4. `[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/nate/test/src/bar.cppfoo [100%] Built target foo`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The target name is `foo` in either case, which threw me off, but the final executable name is still messed up.

Comment: Ah, no worries. Thanks for the help, hopefully I get this sorted out soon :D

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, it seemed unnecessary to post the sources for the example since they didn't actually affect the building, but I should've included the CMakeLists.txt contents. I've since added them.

Comment: Yes, `CMakeLists.txt` is sufficient. (Exactly its code I meant in my previous comment, which is deleted now as obsolete.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is triggered by the line

```
string(REGEX MATCH "^.*/src/(.*)\\.[^.]*$" "" ${src})
```

By specifying `""` for the `<output variable>`, you seem to be trying to ignore it, because you only care about the capture group... but this seems to have some very strange and unfortunate side effects. You can get the same effect with this minimal `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
add_executable(foo ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/foo.cpp)
set("" some_prefix_)
```

I guess this creates a variable whose name is the empty string, but why this would affect the name of the resulting binary is anyone's guess.

Just put `dummy` or `match_output` or whatever, and the problem goes away:

```
string(REGEX MATCH "^.*/src/(.*)\\.[^.]*$" match_output ${src})
```

Comment: Hah! That seems to have done it! That is odd that that would affect a separate call, but thanks for sorting it out!